# Converting DD/MM/YYYY format into YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, date, reverse, netezza

I am struggling with a conversion from  DD/MM/YYYY format into YYYY-MM-DD in NETEZZA.

I was trying some variants but it didn't worked:

```
SELECT REVERSE(contract_end_date) 
from JNK_TABLE (was tried to revers and after do a To_DATE)
    
SELECT RIGHT(contract_end_date) 
from JNK_TABLE
```

Any help will be good.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain what the data type is of. the column.

Comment: CONNECTION_END_DATE CHARACTER VARYING(20),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about converting to a date?

```
select to_date(contract_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Then, fix the data model so that dates are stored as dates.

Once you have it as a date, you can control the format by converting to a string:

```
select to_char(contract_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

If you want to find dates that have errors in the day where the day is `0`, then try:

```
select contract_end_date
from t
where contract_end_date like '0/%' or
      contract_end_date like '00/%';
```

Comment: @joraCrd . . . You have bad data.  Valid dates don't have `0` for the day component.  You need to fix your data somehow.

Comment: the data could be like 05/12/2020, so the day is containing 0

Comment: @joraCrd . . . That is not an issue.  `0/12/2020` would be an issue.

Comment: What’s the data type of the input ‘date’ before conversion? What’s the maximum and minimum value? What’s the ‘longest’ and  ‘shortest’ value? (In case the input is a string)